# Excel return position of the first partial string match in a table, then return position of the last partial string match in the table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have large, ever-growing table that looks like this:

[image: image of table]

I need to find the position of the first instance of "-033" and the position of the last instance of "-033". I have a cell reference for "-033" but other than that, I cannot have any cell references because I don't know the order that the data will come into the table.

I've tried a lot of different things but I keep getting hung up with methods that can't handle multiple instances of the target string.

I do not want to use VBA as I have no experience with it and this will be a shared file.

Comment: What do you want to do once you find these?

Comment: I'll be using the location data to tell me the corresponding date at the top of the column (not shown).

Comment: Is the image of the table showing up? It doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: Yes the table image is showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first column number:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN($A$2:$J$100)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-033",$A$2:$J$100))),1)
```

For last

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,COLUMN($A$2:$J$100)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-033",$A$2:$J$100))),1)
```

Comment: I've hit another road block with this - If there is a cell that contains "-0333", that cell is the one that gets returned, not the cell that contains "-033" only. How can I narrow my results?